# Show Selected Image View on PHPicker

Tags: swift, swiftui, permissions, uiimage, phpickerviewcontroller

I already use PHPicker to view get may image. I want to ask how u show only show selected image when u pick a image? I already try many things and it always show all image in galery. Kindly help.

[image: Permission is selected]

[image: Still show all image]

Here Some Code on View:

```
import Foundation
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var imageToImport: UIImage?
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> some UIViewController {
        
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .images
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        
        let imagePicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            if results.count != 1 {
                return
            }
            
            if let image = results.first {
                
                if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                    image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error  in
                        
                        if let image = image {
                            self.parent.imageToImport = image as? UIImage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.parent.isPresented.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Here in Image Picker:

```
import Foundation
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var imageToImport: UIImage?
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> some UIViewController {
        
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .images
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        
        let imagePicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            if results.count != 1 {
                return
            }
            
            if let image = results.first {
                
                if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                    image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error  in
                        
                        if let image = image {
                            self.parent.imageToImport = image as? UIImage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.parent.isPresented.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show only show image that user only selected. Thanks if u can help me.

[image: Only show selected image not all]

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app

```
let viewController = // The UIViewController from which to present the picker.
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: viewController)
```

or

```
let viewController = // The UIViewController from which to present the picker.
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: viewController) { identifiers in
    for newlySelectedAssetIdentifier in identifiers {
        // Stage asset for app interaction.
    }
}
```

Comment: swiftui with how?

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGida PhotoPicker has everything built in, no authorization required

Comment: if i want to just open Limited photo limited library? how